# What did Euclid mean by his definition of a unit?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Quoting from [this](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html) page:

> A unit is that by virtue of which each of the things that exist is
> called one.

This is how Euclid begins his development of number theory. But what does he mean?

How many such units are there? If we are talking about the number one in the abstract sense, there is only one number 1, at least in our modern understanding.

It's almost as if Euclid is saying the number one (forgetting for a moment that he says 'a unit' not 'the unit', though this could be a mistranslation from Greek, I suppose) is that which gives all things their unity. Is that right?

Now, since he says 'a unit', then this would mean that a unit is essentially the soul of an object, its essence, that which holds it together.

Can anyone with more knowledge chime in?

Comment: Imagine a length, rational or irrational. When it can be divided into equal lengths, those are units. In comparing the units of different  lengths, if they share no units, the lengths are incommensurable. But Euclid may have had slightly different terminology.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Elements beyond book 1, but in book 1 you can be easily led astray by thinking in terms too abstract. It may be the same here. By "unit", Euclid, may just mean a particular magnitude such as a certain length or a certain area.

Comment: Is a sort of platonic form of unit: the common property shard by all things thar are one.

Comment: The page you linked has attached commentary that you can read by clicking on the corresponding definition or proposition. Unit is what is now called [primitive notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion). The "definition" is there just so Euclid can then define numbers as multitudes of units. In multitudes, copies of the unit are each counted as one. He does not fix unit as some single abstract object, his "one" is closer to that, and in different demonstrations some designated segment can serve as a unit to form multitudes from.

Comment: @Conifold thanks, yes, I read the guide, but I was trying to learn even more if possible. If to Euclid unit was a primitive notion, why did he bother offering a definition?

Comment: Same reason modern textbooks give informal explanations of primitives, they just do not call them "definitions". Euclid explained that he will use "unit" for what is counted in multitudes, which is circular as a definition but gives some intuitive idea of what is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some historical considerations may help*...

See e.g. Ivor Grattan-Guinness, [Numbers Magnitudes Ratios and Proportions in Euclid’s Elements (Hist.Math, 1996)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086096900385), page 362: "Euclid presents a theory of positive integers  starting with 2; 1 is a unit,
and there is no zero (7.defs.1–2). The basic combinations and comparisons are
given in Book 7."

And see Lucio Russo, [The Definitions of Fundamental Geometric Entities Contained in Book I of Euclids Elements (Arch.Hist.Ex.Sc., 1998)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004070050016), page 219:

> An interesting, even though indirect, testimony is given by [Iamblichus (ca. 242–ca. 325)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/iamblichus/). At the beginning of Book VII of the *Elements* an unity is defined as that by virtue of which each of the things that exist is called one. Such a definition (which clearly appears Platonic in nature and therefore analogous to the geometrical definitions which we are here discussing) is quoted by Iamblichus, who attributes it to more recent writers. Even though the previously quoted mathematicians are Pythagoreans
> presumably more ancient than Euclid, Iamblichus would hardly have used this
> expression when referring to Euclid. The omission of Euclid in the long list of mathematicians whose definitions of an unity are reported by Iamblichus strongly suggests that there was no definition of an unity in the *Elements* known to Iamblichus. This last testimony is consistent with the hypothesis that more recent authors might have also inserted in the Elements ancient Platonic definitions concerning geometrical terms.
> The above considerations suggest that Euclid did not share the Platonic concept
> which is the ground of the definitions we are here considering.

Thus, we may suppose that the "Platonic flavor" is a later addition due to Neoplatonic scholars; see one of the theree basic principles of Plotinus’ metaphysics, called by him [the One](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plotinus/#ThreFundPrinPlotMeta).

Answer (score 1):

> > A unit is that by virtue of which each of the things that exist is called one.

> How many such units are there?

"Unit" is an abstract notion there: and it really stands for *any* fixed geometric quantity (length, area, etc.) to which we associate *unitary value*, and *relative to which* we can associate a *value* to other geometric quantities (of the same kind): in other words, the *value* of a geometric quantity is the geometric *ratio* between that quantity and the reference "unit" quantity we have chosen.  Indeed, *which* "unit" to choose is simply arbitrary, and it's eventually a choice that has rather to do with practical considerations.

> If we are talking about the number one in the abstract sense, there is only one number 1, at least in our modern understanding.

Yes, just as "unit" is an abstract notion.  Not per chance Euclid, as you say, "[with the (abstract) notion of *unit*] begins his development of number theory".

> It's almost as if Euclid is saying the number one [...] is that which gives all things their unity. Is that right?

I'd say no, of course not: "unit" has *not* to do with "unity", it has to do with "commensurability", itself rather a form a "distinguishability": namely, we can have a concept of "unit" thanks to the fact that we can *compare* (as in, take the ratio of) geometric quantities (of the same kind).

But indeed Euclid in that quote says "each", not "all together", and my paraphrase would be <<any "thing" (that exists) is called "one" (if it is) by virtue of (i.e. with respect to) *a* "unit">> -- although my paraphrase is more of an educated guess: I do not have references to a proper textual analysis from the original.

Answer (score 0):

I start translating Euclid's definitions into modern mathematical language as follows – leaving away any philosophical associations or concepts:

1. The *unit* is the number 1.
2. Each *number* is a finite sum of summands equal to the number 1.
3. For two numbers x, y with x < y: If x divides y, then x is a *part* of y.
4. For two numbers x, y with x < y: If x does not divide y, then x is a *fraction* of y.
5. For two numbers x, y with x < y: If x is a part of y, then y is a
   *multiple* of x.
6. A number x is *even*, if there exists a number y with x = y + y.

What do you think?

Comment: Well, that's fine, thanks, but seeing as this is the philosophy stackexchange, I am kind of interested in the philosophy of it.

Comment: @BenjaminGrange Euclid was a mathematician not a philosopher. My approach is to understand first Euclid's mathematical ideas. Afterwards one can search for philosophical ideas behind his mathematics. I am sceptical that looking with philosophical lenses behind these mathematical definitions brings much insight, neither for mathematics nor for philosophy.

Comment: Euclid may not have been a mathematician but his ideas arose against the background of Greek philosophy, and  guys like Parmenides talked a lot about "the one". I'm wondering if there is (or was in their minds) some connection. To guys like Pythagoras, mathematics was a deeply philosophical enterprise.

Comment: @BenjaminGrange Greek antique spans centuries of time and covers the cultures around the Middle and East Mediterranean Sea. The paradigm of a Greek philosopher who made “The One” to the center of his doctrine was Plotinus. Possibly you find the line Pythagoras – Plato – Plotinus more fruitful for Greek philosophy and philosophical speculation than just Euclid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a a relationship between numbers as abstract entities and the world around us. We can use numbers to express many things, such as ratios, times,  distances, temperatures, prices, crop yields and so on. However, to do so, we must define scales in order to associate a number to a quantity in an unambiguous way. Since one is the basic building block in counting, by extension we consider units to be the basic building block in the scales we use to express quantities. For example, if we are going to quantify distances, we must define what we mean by one amount of distance. If we are to quantify times, we must define what we mean by one amount of time. And so on. A unit is therefore an amount which we equate with the number one.